# cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory error while there is file

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I try to create shared library and compile my `main.c` with this library

I follow this web site : http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

I give these commands :

```
gcc -fPIC -c *.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib -Wl,-soname,libctest.so.1 -o libctest.so.1.0   *.o
sudo mv libctest.so.1.0 /opt/lib
sudo ln -sf /opt/lib/libctest.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libctest.so
sudo ln -sf /opt/lib/libctest.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libctest.so.1
gcc -Wall -L/opt/lib main.c -lctest -o prog
```

Commands gave no error. When I execute binary file `./prog` it gives `./prog: error while loading shared libraries: libctest.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

but `libctest.so.1` is in `/opt/lib`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    24 Aug 18 17:06 libctest.so -> /opt/lib/libctest.so.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    24 Aug 18 17:06 libctest.so.1 -> /opt/lib/libctest.so.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user  user  7064 Aug 18 17:05 libctest.so.1.0
```

Also `ldd prog` is

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe0f559000)
libctest.so.1 => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcd27fc6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcd28371000)
```

so what is wrong ?

I used `debian 8.5` and `gcc 4.9.2`

Comment: You could use the linker `-rpath` option to specify additional places where the executable is to search for libraries, rather than moving them around....

Comment: Thank you @gilez `rpath` solved my problem. If you post ypur comment as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: I expanded my comment into an answer, but as I said, I'm a bit confused now. Are you still having problems, or is this all working?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit, hoping I'm not actually confused any more :-)

Comment: Thanks again @gilez. You solved my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC's `ld` command has an `--rpath` option that may solve your problems:

```
-rpath=dir
       Add a directory to the runtime library search path.
```

You should add the location of your compiled library to GCC's command line when you compile `prog`, via the `-wl` option:

```
-Wl,option
       Pass option as an option to the linker. If option contains commas,
       it is split into multiple options at the commas.
```

So your search path already includes `/opt/lib` because of the original creation of the library:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib
```

For the second compile, add the location of `libctest.so.1.0` as another `rpath`, and it should be found without your needing to move files around:

```
gcc -Wall -L/opt/lib main.c -lctest -Wl,-rpath,/you/dir/name -o prog
```

I think your original effort is failing as the linker has included a hard path to your original outout dir, and then you moved the library from under it.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding /opt/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH as below;

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib
```

Comment: Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has distinct drawback of "polluting" all child processes. When you are in control of the final link, a *much* better solution is to add `-Wl,-rpath=/opt/lib` to the link command instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have a same proplem with [iccxml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iccxml/)

```
iccToXml profile.icc profile.xml
```

When i convert *.icc to *.xml by above code, i recived same message: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, Detail:

```
iccToXml: error while loading shared libraries: libIccXML.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I resolved by use this command before convert

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
```

You can replace "/usr/local/lib" by path of application file that you want.

Wish that is should helpfull for you.